# How to find the magnitude and phase of a transfer function at a specific point in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

for example  the magnitude and phase of  G(s)=1/(s+1) at point 2+i
is there any function in Matlab to calculate that

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the magnitude and phase of a transfer function, that is the frequency response of the transfer function. Once saying this, the evaluation is the frequency (omega) and not a real+imaginary part.

If you want to get the magnitude and phase for a transfer function at a certain frequency, you can use the bode command (https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.bode.html)

So the example will be:

```
% Creating the complex variable "s"
s = tf([1 0],1);
% Creating the transfer function
G = 1/(s+1);
% Get the response at "omega" frequency
freq_radpersec = 5;
% Get the magnitude and phase
[mag,phase] = bode(G,freq_radpersec);
```

Hopefully, this helps to get the magnitude and phase.